# Mojolicious - Can't parse JSON in RESTful

Tags: perl, rest, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

It's impossible to parse JSON in Mojolicious for me. I updated Mojolicious and used before following code, but JSON->new is deprecated.

```
my $json = Mojo::JSON->new;
my $user_request = $json->decode($c->req->body);
my $err = $json->error;
```

from the tutorials, I found out there has been added $self->req->json, but all POSTs to this will result into errors and non working code.

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @body.json http://localhost:3000/checkaddress
```

and my body.json looks like this

```
{
       'id': 1
}
```

Here is my RESTful code in Mojolicious

```
post '/checkaddress' => sub {
my $self = shift;
my $dump = $self->dumper($self->req->json);
};
```

Console log

```
[Sat Feb 20 08:23:27 2016] [debug] 200 OK (0.001688s, 592.417/s)
[Sat Feb 20 08:24:38 2016] [debug] POST "/checkaddress"
[Sat Feb 20 08:24:38 2016] [debug] Routing to a callback
[Sat Feb 20 08:24:38 2016] [debug] undef
```

Calling $self->req->body and then decode_json from Mojo::JSON will result into

```
[error] Malformed JSON: Expected string while parsing object at line 1,  offset 5 at /home/aa/sempt2.pl line 15.
```

So, how to parse JSON correctly now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works with Mojolicious 6.25 and is a complete example:

```
package MyREST;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

use Data::Dumper;

sub startup {
  my $app = shift;

  my $routes = $app->routes;

  $routes->post('/checkaddress' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $data = $self->req->json;
    my $dump = $self->dumper($self->req->json);
    print STDERR $dump;
    $self->render(json => $data);
  });

}

1;
```

For convenience and reliable testing a small client script:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $tx = $ua->post('http://localhost:3000/checkaddress' => json =>
  {
    'id'  => "1",
  }
);
```

This script avoids JSON encoding problems.

Even better would be, to write tests in the Mojolicious style.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it!

```
{
   'id': 1
}
```

it needs to be replaced to

```
{
  "id": 1
}
```

and then id can be then accessed with

```
my $test = decode_json($self->req->body);
$test->{id};
```

And the shortened way

```
my $test = $self->req->json;
$test->{id};
```

is working too!

The errors occured because of the wrong json encoding '', which needs to be "". Hope it helps someone.